# How to add a constant column to a streaming engine in DolphinDB?

Tags: constants, streaming, dolphindb

I add a constant to the metrics of the function `createReactiveStateEngine`, but an error occurs: `A metric shouldn't be a constant`. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a constant to metrics of a streaming engine directly with <"aaa"> or <1> is currently not supported. However, you can convert it to a constant string and add the string:

```
def getConstString(v): take("aaa", v.size()) // v represents any column
```

If it is a numeric constant “k”, you can also add it using the script `<(col-col) + k>` (“col“ represents any column).